# Objective-C category "unrecognized selector" error

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, nsdata, objective-c-category

I have made a UIImage Objective C catagory to house this function:

```
    #import "UIImage+fixOrientation.h"

@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation
{

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}

@end
```

I've impelmented it to the best of my knowledge but for use reason it keeps coming up with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage fixOrientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f0ce270'
```

in my UIImage+fixOrientation.h file my code looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;


@end
```

and my UIImage+fixOrientation.m file consists of the code I posted at the beginning. I've looked into the *other linker flags* in the project target build section with some suggestions but this hasn't helped! I honestly cannot figure out why it can't find this function...

Also this is how I've used the function:

`NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[imageManager pickerImage] fixOrientation], 0.5);`

Does anyone have an idea why it might be throwing me this message? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you imported your category before trying to use it?

Comment: I have yeh, at the top of the file, but it still throws this error :/

Comment: Are you sure that the `.m` file of your category is added to the correct target ?

Comment: This could be the problem... I assume this is what @Eugene was referring to. How would I add the .m file to the correct file? is there documentation somewhere on this subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you've simply forgotten to add that category to the target.

Please take a look to that screenshot and check if it looks the same for you:

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly it! it was assigned to the wrong target. Thanks so much for your help can't believe it was that simple -.- Helped me out a massive amount cheers!

Comment: Why wouldn't this generate a linking error?  I had this problem - it found my header, knew what I was trying to do, but didn't link the symbol - evidently.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `#import UIImage+fixOrientation.h` to any file you wish to use the category in. Alternatively, if the method is generally helpful to the whole project, you can put it inside your `*-Prefix.pch` file so it is available everywhere in the project.

Comment: I've imported it into both of these but still comes up with the error :/.

Comment: He has got crash while missed header would give you a compile-time warning.